# Duplicate Known Types - WCF Exception

Tags: .net, vb.net, wcf

I have the following class:

```
Public Class ClassA

    Private mMyVar  As List( Of ClassB )
    <DataMember (Name:="key")> _
    Public Property MyVar  As List( Of ClassB)
        Get
            Return mMyVar  
        End Get
        Set(value As List( Of ClassB))
            mMyVar  = value
            RaisePropertyChanged( "MyVar" )
        End Set
    End Property

...
```

and:

```
Public Class ClassB

    Private mMyVar  As List( Of IClassC )
    <DataMember (Name:="key2")> _
    Public Property MyVar  As List( Of IClassC)
        Get
            Return mMyVar  
        End Get
        Set(value As List( Of IClassC))
            mMyVar  = value
            RaisePropertyChanged( "MyVar" )
        End Set
    End Property

...
```

Finally, IClassC can be one of several possible actual classes.

I'm getting the following WCF error:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: There was an error while trying to serialize parameter baseEntity The InnerException message was 'Type 'ClassC2' with data contract name ... is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.

I can easily fix this by adding the following decoration to ClassA:

```
<DataContract(Name:= "..." , Namespace:=...), KnownType (GetType (ClassC1)), KnownType (GetType (ClassC2))>
```

(If I add `IClassC` it makes no difference).

This fixes for ClassC1, but for classC2 I get the error:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Type 'ClassC2' cannot be added to list of known types since another type 'ClassC1' with the same data contract name '...' is already present. If there are different collections of a particular type - for example, List and Test[], they cannot both be added as known types.  Consider specifying only one of these types for addition to the known types list.

The message implies that only one known type for an interface can be added.  Is there a way around this, or do I need to pass through the collections as XML or something?